# Как правильно построить логику (фрагменты)?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

В приложении используется `Navigation Drawler`, из которого вызываются фрагменты.
Структура одного из них предоставлена на миниатюре:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно прописать логику, чтобы внутри этого фрагмента при переключении вкладок снизу (каждая из них - это `linearlayout` с `OnClickListener`), менялось только лишь содержимое окно 1 / окно 2. Чтобы сама нижняя часть фрагмента, вкладки - не обновлялись.

Comment: А как вы сейчас делаете так, что обновляется всё?

Comment: Сейчас два фрагмента. Оба включают в себя нижнюю область, различаются лишь верхние - окно 1 / окно 2.

Comment: Возможно, подойдет вариант, когда внутри фрагмента (вся миниатюра) при выборе вкладок внизу, будут скрываться/отображаться элементы окно1/окно2. Попробую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри области "окно 1 / окно 2" расположить два `View` (один под другим) и с помощью кнопок внизу скрывать/отображать окна.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте область "окно 1 / окно 2" контейнером для вложенных фрагментов и меняйте их по клику на вкладки.

Comment: Вся область окно1/2 вкладка1/2 уже и есть фрагмент. Вы имеете ввиду, надо поделить область окон и вкладки еще на два вложенных фрагмента в первый фрагмент? А потом во втором при помощи нового framgentmaneger делать в окнах show hide?

Comment: именно это и имею в виду